# Load scrollable div at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm developing a chat in javascript (angularjs without jQuery), and I would like to know if it's possible to load a scrollable div to the bottom.

I'm aware about the scrollTo js property, but in my case it's not satisfying.

First of all it's not a really good user experience to see the div scrolled to the bottom and furthermore I use onscroll (to top) pagination. So if my div is loaded to his top  when triggered a scroll a new page will be loaded.

[image: Layout of my screen]

In outline I would something close to facebook chat windows.

If anybody know how to do that in an elegant way, thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

Another constraints is that the chat message are loaded asynchronously, so if I only wait for the DOM to be loaded I scroll to the bottom of my empty div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if your chat window is a div with overflow: scroll set (like the FB Chat), wouldn't it work if you set the scrollTop property?

This should set the new scrolling position immediately, so you shold not see any transition.

I created a little CodePen to demonstrate it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpkxl

Comment: Haha, seems like my answer came in one minute too late :-D

Comment: It looks good, but what about if my message contains resources like image. The DOMContentLoaded event doesn't wait for it to be fired. I [tried with the load event but doesn't work](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBAkC).

Comment: I think the load event won't work here, because it gets fired way too early. As far as I understand the problem, scrollHeight contains the wrong value at DOMContentLoaded time, because the height of the image is not known yet and therefore the browser relayouts the container after the image is fully loaded.

You could use onload on every image you load to correct the scrollTop position.

Comment: It seems to be the best option to use the onload image

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
var yourEl= document.getElementById("yourEl");
yourEl.scrollTop = yourEl.scrollHeight;
```

And call it every time new content is added to the div (`yourEl`) in question?

Comment: It should work but when I load old message with the pagination I don't want my div to be scrolled to the bottom, so I need to use a boolean or something to test my case. If there is no other way to do it I'll do it this way but if another way exists I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for scrolling a div to bottom

```
$("element").animate({scrollTop : $("element").height()},1);
```

Comment: The code you suggested relies on jQuery. As far as I understood Takos question, he was looking for a non-jQuery solution "angularjs without jQuery"..

Answer (score 0):

Based Arjun's answer, but using scrollHeight

```
$("element").animate({scrollTop : $("element")[0].scrollHeight},1);
```

will scroll to the [non currently visible] bottom of the element (div/ul/...)

Comment: This is what I was talking about when I said "I'm aware about the scrollTo js property, but in my case it's not satisfying." My mistake I used scrollTo and not scrollTop.